# WildFly command inside domain.sh

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, wildfly

Inside the domain.sh file that comes with WildFly Final 8.0.0 we can see the line in which java is actually being called:

```
eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Process Controller]\" $PROCESS_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS \
\"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/process-controller.log\" \
\"-Dlogging.configuration=file:$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR/logging.properties\" \
-jar \"$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar\" \
-mp \"${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}\" \
org.jboss.as.process-controller \
-jboss-home \"$JBOSS_HOME\" \
-jvm \"$JAVA_FROM_JVM\" \
-mp \"${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}\" \
-- \
\"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/host-controller.log\" \
\"-Dlogging.configuration=file:$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR/logging.properties\" \
$HOST_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS \
-- \
-default-jvm \"$JAVA_FROM_JVM\" \
'"$@"' "&"
```

I understand most of the commands, but I have not being able to find what does the double dashes do "--" in a java argument context. How are the arguments between the two sets of double dashes interpreted by the jvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double dash is used to signify end of the command options. 

If you replace 'eval' on 'echo' you will see doubled OPTS like '-server -Xms64m -Xmx512m' 
This means first settings are for Process Controller after -- you have settings for Host Controller

Comment: Thank you, I found what I was looking for in https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/process-controller/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/process/Main.java. So this way of handling the double dashes is particular for WildFly. I was wondering if it was a Java standard.